# Generating csv file with Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel how make headings returns dynamic array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

In laravel 5.8 generating csv file I use
 https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel
plugin and it works ok, but as I use headings method for header generating
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html

I need to have headers depending on result set I got from the db :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class exportSearchResults implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function collection()
    {
        $searchResultRows = SearchResult
            ::getByUserList($this->user_list_id)
            ->select( 'source_id' )
            ->groupBy( 'source_id' )
            ->orderBy('source_id', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
            ...
        return $searchResultRows;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'field',
            'value',
        ];
        // I need Somehow to return content of this array based on $searchResultRows array in collection method
    }

}
```

Is there is such way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class exportSearchResults implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    private $searchResultRows;

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->searchResultRows;
    }


    public function headings(): array {
         $this->searchResultRows = SearchResult::getByUserList($this->user_list_id)
            ->select( 'source_id' )
            ->groupBy( 'source_id' )
            ->orderBy('source_id', 'asc')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
            ...
        if ($this->searchResultRows ...){
        return [
            'field',
            'value',
        ];
        } else {
          return ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I try this way, but debugging with logging  looks method headings is called at first and collection after that

Comment: You can also try [beforeExport](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html). I didnt use it but give a try..

Comment: To read data twice nto get separately data and headers? Yes that could work.

Comment: Maybe you can do like this. Check update. To avoid DRY.